# Function Declarations and Structure declarations in C

Tags: c, struct, declaration

```
int f(struct r);
struct r
{
int a;
int b;
};
```

The above snippet in a source file throws an error that

```
warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration,
which is probably not what you want for the line int f(struct r)
```

and the following snippet somewhere in the same source file but before the definition of function `f(struct r)`

```
struct r emp;
f(emp);
```

gives an error

```
error:type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete for the line f(emp)
```

but the same thing when the struct is replaced by `typedef`, there were no such such errors...

Is this property to declare an argument in a function declaration before its use is specific to structure alone?

Comment: Is there a way to suppress this warning if I cannot fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the other order:

```
struct r { int a; int b; };
int f(struct r);
```

If you need the function to be declared before the struct, use a forward declaration:

```
struct r;
int f(struct r);
...
struct r { int a; int b; };
int f(struct r anR)
{
    return anR.a + anR.b;
}
```

The problem is that during the compilation of `int f(struct r);` the compiler doesn't see your structure, so it creates some temporary structure instead. Your declaration of the structure later is from the compiler's point of view  not related to the temporary one.

Comment: ok...but the same error has to appear for something like " f(HEY); typedef int HEY; ". But the above error is only for structures alone...that is my question!!!

Comment: @parthiban: because for the `f(HEY)` it's different: compiler assumes that `HEY` is not a type, but a parameter name, and silently adds the type `int` (regardless of any actual type which `HEY` is later typedefed to). It's an old-fashioned behaviour, modern compilers should have issued a warning: http://ideone.com/qQXKS